# Cannot access a string from a method outside of main

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access the filePaths string from the listFilesInDirectory method outside of the main but it is giving me the following error: "The name 'filePaths' does not exist in the current context"

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void listFilesInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            // Let's find some files

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            listFilesInDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you actually mean accessing filePaths, which is defined inside the listFilesInDirectory method, from the Main method ?

Comment: What have you read about scoping in C#? Why do you think Main should be able to access `filePaths`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you cannot access filePaths because it's out of the scope of the method, there are 2 ways you can solve the problem: you either declare a static variable within the class, so that any method can access it, or you make listFilesInDirectory return a string[].

1st method:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static string[] filePaths;

    static void listFilesInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
    {
        // Let's find some files
       filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Receive the return from listFilesInDirectory();
        listFilesInDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that this method will overwrite the filePaths variable every time you call listFilesInDirectory)

2nd method:

```
internal class Program
{
    static string[] listFilesInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
    {
        // Let's find some files
        return filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] filePaths = listFilesInDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you use the second method, because it's cleaner, more readable  and less errore prone

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access something out of scope and fail to return the output of the `Directory.GetFiles`. What you would want to do would be along the following:

```
public class Startup
{
     public static void Main(string[] arguments)
     {
           var files = GetFilesFromPath("Location Here");
           foreach(var file in files)
                Console.WriteLine(file);
     }

     public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesFromPath(string path) => Directory.GetFiles(path);
}
```

The code will have potential errors, but the point would be the lambda will return the files.  Then inside the main you do a variable with those values, then you can iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

Even if both are static, you can't access information from outside. They have to communicate. If you send information, you'll receive a new information back.

**listFilesInDirectory** is a void **method**, which doens't return nothing.
You need to change its return to **string[]**, return the filePaths to some variable, then you can do the foreach on 'filePaths'.

```
internal class Program
    {       //Instead of void, set the method to return a string[]
        static string[] listFilesInDirectory(string workingDirectory)
        {
            // Let's find some files
            // Return this string[]
            return string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(workingDirectory);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Receive the return from listFilesInDirectory();
            string[] filePaths = listFilesInDirectory(@"C:\Temp");
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

This should work.

And btw, listFilesInDirectory() is a **method**. You should always start a method name with a upper letter. :)

Comment: *You need to* is very prescriptive; there are other ways to achieve inter-method communication of data

Comment: As you meantioned on the question comments about the OP's knowledge about scoping, do you think this is a relevant information right now?
He's on the way to understanding programming, I think. Then, _you need to_ it's the best thing to tell him in this moment.